# How does changing the password of the connected database affect the application while operating the spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I would like to know if changing the password of the DB associated with the Spring boot application affects the existing connections.
If Hikari tries to connect by reading the properties at regular intervals when managing the connection, I think there could be a connection error in this process, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does affects the connection, it will cause something like "Error establishing a database connection".